# Change svg coordinates onend

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I have a SVG of paths and foreignObjects. `Onclick`, it triggers an animation, then updates the coordinates accordingly by calling a function using the `onend` attribute. This works as it should with the path objects, but when I try to call the function to update the coordinates of the foreignObjects, it doesn't render correctly - they appear in the wrong place even though the code shows the correct x and y values and they are no longer layered on top of the path objects. How can I correct this?

This jsfiddle illustrates the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/kxg2eg27/10/

Comment: Please add a [mcve] to the question. There's far too much going on here and it's a link rather than being part of the question itself.

Comment: I played with it for more than 2 hours now...  Added a lot `console.log()`... I've fixed things... But there is still an annoying "flicking" that occurs `onend` and I don't know how to patch this. See my [**Fddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Bes7weB/7dff4zLc/) -- So I leave it to like this... ;)